# Clickhouse cannot alter columns throws DB::Exception: Metadata on replica is not up to date with common metadata in Zookeeper

Tags: database, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I have a replicated merge tree table on two nodes

I have two columns as client_port and server_port `Int16`, I want to change it to `UInt16`. There is currently alot of data in this table (somewhere around 1.2TB with 20billion rows)

On running these queries one by one,

```
Alter table events_db.events_local_tables ON cluster click_cluster modify COLUMN client_port `UInt16`

Alter table events_db.events_local_tables ON cluster click_cluster modify COLUMN server_port `UInt16`
```

client_port was not straight forward, it did its changes on 1 node but for the other node we had to restart all zookeeper services manually. Eventually managed to change client_port but the same flow didn't work for server_port fails. It throws the following exception.

```
2021.09.20 20:24:16.761842 [ 38517 ] {806f2936-b668-41aa-ab7c-16c485393b17} <Debug> executeQuery: (from 10.120.1.122:54962)  /*TABIX_QUERY_ID_uUtFccK4*/ Alter table events_db.events_local_tables ON cluster click_cluster modify COLUMN server_port `UInt16`
2021.09.20 20:24:16.761941 [ 38517 ] {806f2936-b668-41aa-ab7c-16c485393b17} <Trace> ContextAccess (default): Access granted: ALTER MODIFY COLUMN(server_port) ON events_db.events_local_tables
2021.09.20 20:24:16.773835 [ 38666 ] {} <Debug> DDLWorker: Processing task query-0000000482 (ALTER TABLE events_db.events_local_tables ON CLUSTER click_cluster MODIFY COLUMN `server_port` UInt16)
2021.09.20 20:24:16.779570 [ 38666 ] {} <Debug> DDLWorker: Executing query: ALTER TABLE events_db.events_local_tables MODIFY COLUMN `server_port` UInt16
2021.09.20 20:24:16.795296 [ 38666 ] {fb879340-1376-4af0-927b-4e8b73575841} <Debug> executeQuery: (from 0.0.0.0:0, user: ) /* ddl_entry=query-0000000482 */ ALTER TABLE events_db.events_local_tables MODIFY COLUMN `server_port` UInt16
2021.09.20 20:24:16.832801 [ 38666 ] {fb879340-1376-4af0-927b-4e8b73575841} <Error> executeQuery: Code: 517. DB::Exception: Metadata on replica is not up to date with common metadata in Zookeeper. Cannot alter. (CANNOT_ASSIGN_ALTER) (version 21.9.2.17 (official build)) (from 0.0.0.0:0) (in query: /* ddl_entry=query-0000000482 */ ALTER TABLE events_db.events_local_tables MODIFY COLUMN `server_port` UInt16), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):
2021.09.20 20:24:16.833070 [ 38666 ] {fb879340-1376-4af0-927b-4e8b73575841} <Error> DDLWorker: Query ALTER TABLE events_db.events_local_tables MODIFY COLUMN `server_port` UInt16 wasn't finished successfully: Code: 517. DB::Exception: Metadata on replica is not up to date with common metadata in Zookeeper. Cannot alter. (CANNOT_ASSIGN_ALTER), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):
2021.09.20 20:24:17.274010 [ 38666 ] {b001d5b7-d564-413d-82fc-001ec82906b6} <Debug> executeQuery: (from 0.0.0.0:0, user: ) /* ddl_entry=query-0000000482 */ ALTER TABLE events_db.events_local_tables MODIFY COLUMN `server_port` UInt16
2021.09.20 20:24:17.313598 [ 38666 ] {b001d5b7-d564-413d-82fc-001ec82906b6} <Error> executeQuery: Code: 517. DB::Exception: Metadata on replica is not up to date with common metadata in Zookeeper. Cannot alter. (CANNOT_ASSIGN_ALTER) (version 21.9.2.17 (official build)) (from 0.0.0.0:0) (in query: /* ddl_entry=query-0000000482 */ ALTER TABLE events_db.events_local_tables MODIFY COLUMN `server_port` UInt16), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):
2021.09.20 20:24:17.313893 [ 38666 ] {b001d5b7-d564-413d-82fc-001ec82906b6} <Error> DDLWorker: Query ALTER TABLE events_db.events_local_tables MODIFY COLUMN `server_port` UInt16 wasn't finished successfully: Code: 517. DB::Exception: Metadata on replica is not up to date with common metadata in Zookeeper. Cannot alter. (CANNOT_ASSIGN_ALTER), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):
2021.09.20 20:24:17.429943 [ 38666 ] {2db93657-4c33-4b9d-8817-653f9706a27c} <Debug> executeQuery: (from 0.0.0.0:0, user: ) /* ddl_entry=query-0000000482 */ ALTER TABLE events_db.events_local_tables MODIFY COLUMN `server_port` UInt16
2021.09.20 20:24:17.481732 [ 38666 ] {2db93657-4c33-4b9d-8817-653f9706a27c} <Error> executeQuery: Code: 517. DB::Exception: Metadata on replica is not up to date with common metadata in Zookeeper. Cannot alter. (CANNOT_ASSIGN_ALTER) (version 21.9.2.17 (official build)) (from 0.0.0.0:0) (in query: /* ddl_entry=query-0000000482 */ ALTER TABLE events_db.events_local_tables MODIFY COLUMN `server_port` UInt16), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):
2021.09.20 20:24:17.482099 [ 38666 ] {2db93657-4c33-4b9d-8817-653f9706a27c} <Error> DDLWorker: Query ALTER TABLE events_db.events_local_tables MODIFY COLUMN `server_port` UInt16 wasn't finished successfully: Code: 517. DB::Exception: Metadata on replica is not up to date with common metadata in Zookeeper. Cannot alter. (CANNOT_ASSIGN_ALTER), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):
2021.09.20 20:24:18.290940 [ 38517 ] {806f2936-b668-41aa-ab7c-16c485393b17} <Error> executeQuery: Code: 341. DB::Exception: There was an error on [10.120.1.117:9000]: Cannot execute replicated DDL query, maximum retries exceeded. (UNFINISHED) (version 21.9.2.17 (official build)) (from 10.120.1.122:54962) (in query:  /*TABIX_QUERY_ID_uUtFccK4*/ Alter table events_db.events_local_tables ON cluster click_cluster modify COLUMN server_port `UInt16` ), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):
```

If someone understands these logs let us know whats the straight forward flow for changing column types in Distributed tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it's NOT documented but it's expected behaivor if you send several alter to different replicas (because you use on cluster )

```
On running these queries one by one,
Alter table events_db.events_local_tables ON cluster click_cluster modify COLUMN client_port `UInt16`
Alter table events_db.events_local_tables ON cluster click_cluster modify COLUMN server_port `UInt16`
```

Need to wait until the first alter completed at **all replicas**!!!! before sending the next.

Or send all alters in a single  command

```
Alter table events_db.events_local_tables ON cluster click_cluster 
   modify COLUMN client_port `UInt16`,
   modify COLUMN server_port `UInt16`;
```

Comment: I understand thats default behavior of clickhouse but when I run this from clickhouse-client: `Alter table events_db.events_local_tables ON cluster click_cluster modify COLUMN server_port `UInt16` gives me DB::Exception: Metadata on replica is not up to date with common metadata in Zookeeper. Cannot alter. (PS detach/attach table doesn't help neither does SYSTEM RESTART REPLICA events_local_tables)

Comment: I run same command on a different node it gives, ```There was an error on [10.120.1.117:9000]: Cannot execute replicated DDL query, maximum retries exceeded.``` so its obviously the issue in the comment above

Comment: check metadata version in ZK in 2(n)! places in the table metadata and in the all /replicas

Comment: This problem branches to a different solution, we had low space on zookeeper nodes, with snapshots taking upto 50G which caused all these issues, cleanup on zookeeper using ```./zkCleanup.sh -n 5``` did the trick but not for long, maybe have to look into [snapshots_to_keep](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/clickhouse-keeper/)

Comment: But we use zookeeper, and moving to clickhouse keeper in production environment idk doesn't sound right. @denny-crane have any idea how much size of snapshots+logs required with 2 CH nodes with 3 Zookeepers

Comment: check CH documentation about Zookeeper time bomb. Zookeeper needs 1 recent snapshot and logs after that snapshot to be able to start and restore database in-memory. Usually users store 3 recent snapshot for safety (sometimes snapshot can be lost during unexpected hardware reboot.